# Is fixing a broken link not a substantial enough improvement to be allowed to bypass the 6 character edit rule?

Tags: bug, edits, feedback

There was a broken link on the selected answer to this question:-

[Forking a new version of my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230399/forking-a-new-version-of-my-application/6230506#6230506)

However, when I made the edit to update the link it would not let me submit unless I changed 6 characters.

Should the 6 characters not include the links?

**I would argue that fixing a broken link in a *"link only"* answer that only really provides any value through said link, is a substantial improvement from almost zero value to some value, and *should be allowed***

Comment: Because while counting characters might not be the most accurate metric of substance, it is the easiest to implement.

Comment: @SamIam I don't expect that it would be hard to implement allowing edits to links - these have to be parsed by the markdown parser anyway, so are already distinct entities from the main text

Comment: And saying that it's the easiest implementation isn't an answer to whether or not that implementation is sufficient

Comment: That's something I wanted to know too.

Comment: @rgvcorley well in that case it's a good thing that the question asking `Why does the 6 character edit limit apply even if I am fixing a broken link?`, and not asking `is that implementation sufficient`.

Comment: @SamIam do you dissagree with "I would argue that fixing a broken link in an answer that only really provides any value through the link that is provided in it, is a substantial improvement from almost zero value to some value"?

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more accurate to what I was really meaning to ask. Maybe you could have something constructive to add to the discussion

Answer (score 1):

Edits should be substantive, and this really isn't.

In most cases there is a good chance that there's something else that can be improved about a post which you should try and find to make the edit more important.

In this case that answer is quite low quality as it's basically link-only, and you could have improved it further by including the relevant parts of the link into the post to stop it from being low quality instead of putting junk into the post.

Comment: "putting junk into the post"? So fixing a broken link in an answer that (as you say yourself) is of low quality and the only value it brings is the link, is adding junk to the post?

Comment: I'd argue that fixing a broken link in an answer that only has value through the link provided is a substantial improvement from almost zero value to some value

Comment: @rgvcorley No, adding junk to the post is adding junk to the post. And this is junk: `(won't let me fix the broken link without adding more than 6 characters)`.